# How do I create an array from columns?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How do I create an array from database columns?

My table Reklamer:

```
id  virksomhed  dato                   klik     
10  Iqmedier    2011-02-15 00:00:00     4   
11  Iqmedier    2011-02-15 00:00:00     2   
12  Iqmedier    2011-02-15 00:00:00     3
```

I want to create an array of all the columns klik. Like `[4, 2, 3]`

An can someone explain what a block and an object is :) Or where I can read something about it.

Comment: @Rails beginner, FYI, on StackOverflow they discourage using greetings (salutations), signatures and thanking people in advance or "best regards" and similar (validictions).

Comment: And they also discourage having "Simple qu[e]stion" in the question title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you have a model named `Reklamer` too.

You can do the following to get the array

```
Reklamer.select('klik').all.map(&:klik)
```

Edit:

([Array.map](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000249) in Ruby)
`map(&:klik)` is just a shorthand for

```
.map do |record|
  record.klik
end
```

It returns the value of `klik` for each record, and creates a new array using those values.

Comment: What does .map(&:klik)? Does it create an array?

Comment: How do i only create an array of those were the column Virksomhed = Iqmedier. I have tried with this         data: <%= Reklamer.select(:all, :conditions => {:virksomhed => 'Iqmedier'}).select('earn').all.map(&:earn) %> But gets a error: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)

Comment: Try `Reklamer.where(:virksomhed => 'Iqmedier').all.map(&:earn)`